# How to convert two different strings to date format and finding their differences in JSP/JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jsp

I have 2 strings
Str1: 2016-7-25.15.38. 32. 0 (This is what im getting from DB)
String2 : July 25, 2016 3:19 PM (This one I wrote a program to read from the email timestamp)

How to convert these 2 strings to date format and find their differnce in time.. Pls help. 
Ive gone through so many pages in SO and google but not getting anything specific

Comment: 2016-7-25.15.38. 32. 0  and July 25, 2016 3:19 PM both are java.sql.Timestamps?

Comment: You can also use DateUtils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to convert these 2 strings to date format

Using Java 8, you'd parse them like this:

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
ZonedDateTime dt1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-7-25.15.38. 32. 0",
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-M-d.H.m. s. 0").withZone(zoneId));
ZonedDateTime dt2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("July 25, 2016 3:19 PM",
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, uuuu h:mm a").withZone(zoneId));
```

<sup>*Using a non-standard indentation to align format string with value to be parsed, for easier comparison.*</sup>

The code is using [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) so Daylight Savings Time will be handled correctly.

---

> and find their difference in time

Getting the difference in time is then easy enough, using [`until()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) or [`between()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-):

```
long seconds = dt1.until(dt2, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(dt1, dt2);
```

They are the same. Use whichever you like best.

---

If you print the values above, you get (I'm in USA Eastern time zone):

```
2016-07-25T15:38:32-04:00[America/New_York]
2016-07-25T15:19-04:00[America/New_York]
-1172
```

Comment: What if he is not using java8? he did not tagged this question under "java 8" ? Then How you got this idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use Oracle to figure out the difference. It's quite easy:

select to_date('2016-07-25.15.38.32', 'yyyy-mm-dd.hh24.mi.ss') - to_date('July 25, 2016 3:19 PM', 'Month dd, yyyy hh:mi PM')
from dual

Answer (score -1):

1.**Convert java.sql.timestamp into java.util.Date**

```
Date startDate = new Date(startTimestamp.getTime());
Date endDate= new Date(endTimestamp.getTime());
```

2.You can find the **time difference** using [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum as below.

```
Date startDate = // Set start date
Date endDate   = // Set end date

long duration  = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
```

and so on..

Comment: Where did you get the idea that values are `Timestamp` objects, when question says *"I have 2 strings"* and goes on asking *"How to convert these 2 strings to date format"*?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Andreas, I got the idea from the format of those strings 2016-7-25.15.38. 32. 0 and assumed it is timestamp